# Можете пожалуйста объяснить, что этот метод делает?

Tags: c#

```
public static double[][] Allocate(int numberOfClusters, int numberOfFeatures) 
{
    double[][] result = new double[numberOfClusters][];
    for (int k = 0; k < numberOfClusters; ++k) { 
        result[k] = new double[numberOfFeatures];
        Console.WriteLine(k + "->" + result[k]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Выделяет память под массив массивов (то есть двумерный массив)

Comment: double[][] result = new double[numberOfClusters][]; создает 2D массив, где количество строк = numberOfClusters. Я не понимаю, что происходит в for-блоке

Answer (score 1):

Создаёт рваный двумерный массив `numberOfClusters` строк, каждая из которых содержит `numberOfClusters` элементов `double`. Ну и зачем-то выводит на консоль все строки-массивы.

Comment: Выводить вовсе не нужно,это я для себя хотела посмотреть, какие элементы содержаться в матрице.

Comment: @olmar102, нолики.